# Locking tables in mysql using php errors

Tags: php, mysql, locking

I am trying to implement a table lock on my database for a sample shopping website hosted locally.

The following is a sample of my index.php:

```
case "add":             
    if(!empty($_POST["quantity"])) {
        if(!isset($timestamp)){
            $timestamp = time();
            $lock = $db_handle->runQuery("LOCK TABLE orders_f write, prod_f read");
        }
        $productByCode = $db_handle->runQuery("SELECT * FROM prod_f WHERE code='" . $_GET["code"] . "'");
        $itemArray = array($productByCode[0]["code"]=>array('name'=>$productByCode[0]["name"], 'code'=>$productByCode[0]["code"], 'quantity'=>$_POST["quantity"], 'price'=>$productByCode[0]["price"]));

        if(!empty($_SESSION["cart_item"])) {
            if(in_array($productByCode[0]["code"],array_keys($_SESSION["cart_item"]))) {
                foreach($_SESSION["cart_item"] as $k => $v) {
                    if($productByCode[0]["code"] == $k) {
                        if(empty($_SESSION["cart_item"][$k]["quantity"])) {
                            $_SESSION["cart_item"][$k]["quantity"] = 0;
                        }
                        $_SESSION["cart_item"][$k]["quantity"] += $_POST["quantity"];
                    }
                }
            } else {
                $_SESSION["cart_item"] = array_merge($_SESSION["cart_item"],$itemArray);
            }
        } else {
            $_SESSION["cart_item"] = $itemArray;
        }
```

Where the table lock has been enforced. I get the following error when I try to add in the cart, which is the source of the case statement above:

> Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in path\dbcontroller.php on line 24
>   Here is a snippet of my dbcontroller.php:

```
function runQuery($query) {
    $result = mysqli_query($this->conn,$query);
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $resultset[] = $row;
    }       
    if(!empty($resultset))
        return $resultset;
    else
        return false;
}
```

I've been searching all night on Youtube and on Stackoverflow but none of the options seem to be working. It is on an `Apache` server using Wamp on a `64 bit Windows 10` machine. Please, any suggestions are welcomed.

Comment: Why do you use table locks in the first place?

Comment: It's a requirement to prevent other users from accessing the product table for 10 mins while a user has added an item to their cart.

Comment: Use mysqli in exception mode, to get usefull error messages: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22662488/mysqli-fetch-assoc-expects-parameter-call-to-a-member-function-bind-param

Comment: Okay, i'll try that and let you know what happens

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Table 'prod_f' was not locked with LOCK TABLES in path\dbcontroller.php on line 23. mysqli_sql_exception: Table 'prod_f' was not locked with LOCK TABLES in

Comment: I agree with @YuriG, locking tables for 10 minutes is an overkill. It effectively means that you can only have 1 customer at a time with anything in their carts. Unless this is a specific requirement in your assignment, I would forget about this.

Comment: Yes it is a requirement. I'm thinking of an alternative if i can't get to resolve the locking table error. Which is to get the timestamp when the a user adds and item to the cart, add that time to the $_Server superglobal if it is not already set. Then when new users try to add i do a check to see if the difference between timestamps is greater than 10 mins, if so then the query is allowed to run otherwise the user has to wait.